# Как настроить Wi-Fi в Windows XP

Tags: windows, сеть, wifi, windows-xp

Wi-Fi Adapter Atheros AR5006EG, у меня на ноуте две ОС, одна XP, вторая Ubuntu. Так вот, этот же самый адаптер не видит в XP, но когда я загружаюсь из-под Ubuntu, то адаптер прекрасно работает, находит все сети и т.д. У меня стоит и так последний драйвер. Скриншоты устройства и его параметры.

[image]

Comment: И что мешает http://ixbt.radarsync.com/ItemDetails.aspx?itemid=160974

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Была подобная ситуация, под Windows установил в бреду какой-то костыль и заработало, под Ubuntu пришлось поменять прошивку устройства.  так что рекомендую копать именно в этом направлении.

Comment: угу, вот и я костыль установил, называется Wireless Console Utilit, без него не фурычило, а щас норм.

Answer (score 1):

Так понимаю не видит сети в XP. Удалите его как устройство из "Диспечер устройств". Так же если с драйвером ставились доп утилиты подключения и поиска сетей, удалите их тоже. Вытащите устройство, перезагрузите комп. Вставте адаптер в компьютер.

Comment: у меня ноут вообще-то, на нем две ОСи, одна Ubuntu, вторая Windows XP, когда с Ubuntu загружаюсь, то Wi-Fi адаптер работает нормально, находит сети, и мой роутер тоже, но когда этот же адаптер из под Windows XP SP3 Home запускаю, он сети не видит, из устройств удалял, переустанавливал, ничего не дало.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте службы. Win+R >>> services.msc Я сейчас винды перед глазами не имею, названия перечислить не могу. Но они вполне себе информативные, чтобы понять, зависит wi-fi от работы этой службы или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если в ХР установлен нативный софт адаптера, то он может перехватить управление на себя, и тогда в родном виндовом подключении никаких вай-фай сетей действительно видно не будет! В общем, либо подключайтесь через родной Атеросовский софт, либо переключайтесь на родной виндовый! (Там где-то в свойствах подключения такой тег есть.)